# what is the equivalent function for FormatNbr(DTSSource("Commission_Rate_2"), 8, 4) in informatica

Tags: informatica, iics

In DTS function DTSDestination("Commission_Rate_2") = FormatNbr(DTSSource("Commission_Rate_2"), 8, 4) converting the input 652.5 as 06525000  and 9.75 as 00097500
what is the equivalent function to convert column value as 652.5 and required output as 06525000 in informatica.

Ex : for input 9.75 need output as 00097500
and for input 652.5 need output as 06525000

Comment: What is `FormatNbr()` there is no function in VBScript called that do you mean [`FormatNumber()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ws343esk(v=vs.84))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lpad` and multiply by 10000.
Use

```
LPAD((col*10000),8,'0')
```

col*10000 - will made 9.75 to 97500
lpad(97500  ,'0',8) - will output 00097500

Pls note this will be a string data type.

Comment: There is no function in VBScript called `LPAD()`?

Comment: Thanks for sending the code. it is working for me @ 
Koushik Roy. Small correction instead of LPAD((col*10000),'0',8) it is LPAD((col*10000),8,'0')

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it, it was a typo...