# how to convert 99.0000 to 009900 in informatica iics

Tags: informatica, iics

In DTSDestination("Ann_Non_Comm_Prem") = FormatNbr(DTSSource("Ann_Non_Comm_Prem"),6,2) converting the input 0.0000 as 000000 and 99.0000 as 009900 what is the equivalent function to convert column value as 99.0000 and required output as 009900 in informatica.

Ex : for input 99.0000 need output as 009900

I used LPAD(COL1*10000,6,'0') but it is not working.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the equivalent function for FormatNbr(DTSSource("Commission\_Rate\_2"), 8, 4) in informatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123643/what-is-the-equivalent-function-for-formatnbrdtssourcecommission-rate-2-8)

Comment: No this is not answered. this is the different one.

Comment: I gave a generic solution which can be used for any such function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls use this...
(Pls note this data type would be string)

```
LPAD(COL1*100,6,'0')
```

And this is the generic solution.
Function to be replaced is `FormatNbr(DTSSource("Ann_Non_Comm_Prem"),6,2)`.
Now, look at arguments - 6 and 2. So, 6 is for 0-padding and 2 is power of 10 (10^2 or 100).

So for above example, equivalent function will be

```
Lpad(col1*10^2,6,'0') or lpad(col1*100,6,'0)
```

Comment: This is not working for me, still i am getting the output as 14600. instead of 001460

Comment: Because the data type isnt string its int. Pls modify the output data type to string and it will work.